# sum two rows of data based on criteria(merge two result set totals)

Tags: sql, sum, case, grouping

I am trygin to add the two rows of data as a single sum in this query(455000 and 456000 should show as single row). initially i have 9 results but i want to add 455000 and 456000 as a single result and have only 8 results in the query.[result set with 9 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y39Z4.jpg)[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cr6wgo8o1rqskze/result%20set.jpg?dl=0)

```sql
SELECT     BF_BDOB.CD, BF_BDOB.NM, MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL.BF_ORGN_PARN_CD, ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN [BF_TM_PERD_RLUP_VW].BF_TM_PERD_PARN_CD = 'PY2ACT' THEN bf_data.data ELSE 0 END), 0) AS PY2ACT 
FROM        BF_BDOB INNER JOIN
                  BF_DATA INNER JOIN
                  BF_BDOB_RLUP ON BF_DATA.BF_BDOB_ID = BF_BDOB_RLUP.BF_BDOB_CHLD_ID INNER JOIN
                  MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL ON BF_DATA.BF_ORGN_ID = MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL.ID ON BF_BDOB.ID = BF_BDOB_RLUP.BF_BDOB_PARN_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  BF_TM_PERD_RLUP_VW ON BF_DATA.BF_TM_PERD_CD = BF_TM_PERD_RLUP_VW.CD
WHERE     (BF_BDOB_RLUP.RLUP_NUM = 3)
GROUP BY BF_BDOB_RLUP.BF_BDOB_PARN_ID, BF_BDOB.NM, MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL.BF_ORGN_PARN_CD, MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL.BF_ORGN_CNSL_SLCN_CD, MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL.XTRN_LEVL, BF_BDOB.OBJ_TYP,BF_BDOB.CD
HAVING     (MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL.BF_ORGN_CNSL_SLCN_CD = '2324') AND (MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL.XTRN_LEVL = '3') AND (MV_BF_ORGN_CNSL.BF_ORGN_PARN_CD = '5100000') AND (BF_BDOB.OBJ_TYP = 'R') AND (BF_BDOB.CD IN ('451000', '453000', '454000', '455000', '456000', '477000', 
                  '478000', '495000', '498000'))
```

rows 3 and 4 should show as a single line item(the sum of row 3 and 4), right now they are separate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, since you are grouping by CD and BF_BDOB.NM, you could try make a mapping table where the output has the tag you need to sum, something like:

Mapping Table:

```
|CD_MAP|NM_MAP|MAP_DESCRIPTION|
|456000|LOCAL REVENUES|LOCAL REVENUES/GRANTS|
|456000|LOCAL GRANTS|LOCAL REVENUES/GRANTS|
```

Then you can join this to your main query to group by MAP_DESCRIPTION.

NOTE: Try to use Aliases on your query because is not easy to read.